# Cannot find module 'typescript' | Ionic 4

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, node-modules, ionic4

I pull the ionic 4 code from git to my pc and tried to run it and it shows "Cannot find module 'typescript'" even I installed it already by using

> npm install typescript

and also installed globally by

> npm install -g typescript

**Error log:**

```
[ng] Cannot find module 'typescript'
[ng] Error: Cannot find module 'typescript'
[ng]     at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:581:15)
[ng]     at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:507:25)
[ng]     at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:637:17)
[ng]     at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:22:18)
[ng]     at C:\Users\win123\node_modules\@angular\compiler-cli\src\diagnostics\typescript_symbols.js:22:14
[ng]     at C:\Users\win123\node_modules\@angular\compiler-cli\src\diagnostics\typescript_symbols.js:10:17

[ng]     at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\win123\node_modules\@angular\compiler-cli\src\diagnostics\typescript_symbols.js:16:3)
[ng]     at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:689:30)
[ng]     at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:700:10)
[ng]     at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:599:32)
[ng]     at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:538:12)
[ng]     at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:530:3)
[ng]     at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:637:17)
[ng]     at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:22:18)
[ng]     at C:\Users\win123\node_modules\@angular\compiler-cli\index.js:30:32
[ng]     at C:\Users\win123\node_modules\@angular\compiler-cli\index.js:3:17

[ERROR] ng has unexpectedly closed (exit code 1).
```

Additionally, i also tried

> npm install @ionic/app-scripts@latest --save-dev

this command, but it doesn't work.

Can anyone help me with this issue?

**UPDATE 1**

```
$ ionic info
[ERROR] Error loading @ionic/angular-toolkit package.json: Error: Cannot find module '@ionic/angular-toolkit/package'
[ERROR] Error loading @angular/cli package.json: Error: Cannot find module '@angular/cli/package'
[ERROR] Error loading @angular-devkit/build-angular package.json: Error: Cannot find module
        '@angular-devkit/build-angular/package'
[ERROR] Error loading @angular-devkit/schematics package.json: Error: Cannot find module
        '@angular-devkit/schematics/package'


Ionic:

   ionic (Ionic CLI)             : 4.7.0
   Ionic Framework               : @ionic/angular 4.0.0-rc.0
   @angular-devkit/build-angular : not installed
   @angular-devkit/schematics    : not installed
   @angular/cli                  : not installed
   @ionic/angular-toolkit        : not installed

Cordova:

   cordova (Cordova CLI) : 8.1.2 (cordova-lib@8.1.1)
   Cordova Platforms     : not available
   Cordova Plugins       : not available

System:

   Android SDK Tools : 25.2.3 (E:\AndroidSDK)
   NodeJS            : v10.14.2 (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe)
   npm               : 6.4.1
   OS                : Windows 7
```

**UPDATE 2**

Package.json

```
{
  "name": "MyApp",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "author": "Ionic Framework",
  "homepage": "http://ionicframework.com/",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^7.1.4",
    "@angular/cdk": "^7.2.0",
    "@angular/common": "~7.1.4",
    "@angular/core": "~7.1.4",
    "@angular/forms": "~7.1.4",
    "@angular/http": "~7.1.4",
    "@angular/material": "^7.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~7.1.4",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~7.1.4",
    "@angular/router": "~7.1.4",
    "@ionic-native/core": "5.0.0-beta.21",
    "@ionic-native/splash-screen": "5.0.0-beta.21",
    "@ionic-native/status-bar": "5.0.0-beta.21",
    "@ionic/angular": "4.0.0-rc.0",
    "@ionic/cli-plugin-ionic-angular": "^1.4.1",
    "@ionic/pro": "2.0.4",
    "@ionic/storage": "^2.2.0",
    "cordova-android": "7.0.0",
    "cordova-plugin-device": "^2.0.2",
    "cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard": "^2.1.3",
    "cordova-plugin-ionic-webview": "^2.3.1",
    "cordova-plugin-splashscreen": "^5.0.2",
    "cordova-plugin-statusbar": "^2.4.2",
    "cordova-plugin-whitelist": "^1.3.3",
    "core-js": "^2.5.4",
    "firebase": "^5.7.2",
    "ionic": "^4.7.0",
    "moment": "^2.23.0",
    "ngx-material-timepicker": "^2.11.0",
    "rxjs": "~6.3.3",
    "zone.js": "~0.8.26"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/architect": "~0.11.4",
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.11.4",
    "@angular-devkit/core": "~7.1.4",
    "@angular-devkit/schematics": "~7.1.4",
    "@angular/cli": "^7.1.4",
    "@angular/compiler": "~7.1.4",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~7.1.4",
    "@angular/language-service": "~7.1.4",
    "@ionic/angular-toolkit": "^1.2.2",
    "@ionic/app-scripts": "^3.2.1",
    "@ionic/lab": "1.0.16",
    "@types/jasmine": "~2.8.8",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "@types/node": "~10.12.0",
    "codelyzer": "~4.5.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.99.1",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "~3.1.4",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~2.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.2",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "protractor": "~5.4.0",
    "ts-node": "~7.0.0",
    "tslint": "~5.12.0",
    "typescript": "^3.2.2"
  },
  "description": "An Ionic project",
  "cordova": {
    "plugins": {
      "cordova-plugin-whitelist": {},
      "cordova-plugin-statusbar": {},
      "cordova-plugin-device": {},
      "cordova-plugin-splashscreen": {},
      "cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard": {},
      "cordova-plugin-ionic-webview": {
        "ANDROID_SUPPORT_ANNOTATIONS_VERSION": "27.+"
      }
    },
    "platforms": [
      "android"
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/186338/discussion-on-question-by-jaydip-kalkani-cannot-find-module-typescript-ionic).

Answer (score 1):

Try to rm -rf node_modules and then npm i